# Changing an image button in a user control from outside the control

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

In Visual Studio, I have built an ASP.NET user control which constitutes an image button. The image file for it is now 1.jpg. I'd like, by clicking a (regular) button in the main frame, to turn it into 2.jpg. How can I do this (in c#)?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is via `FindControl("Id")` to dig out the `ImageButton` from `UserControl`

UsrCtrl.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeBehind="UsrCtrl.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebLab.UsrCtrl" %>
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/1.jpg" />
```

Default.aspx

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <uc1:UsrCtrl runat="server" id="UsrCtrl1" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" 
            OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Button Click

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var imgBtn = UsrCtrl1.FindControl("ImageButton1") as ImageButton;
    imgBtn.ImageUrl = "~/Images/2.jpg";
}
```

You can make the `ImageButton` a public property of `UserControl` to acheive more intuitively access.

Answer (score 0):

Add a public property within `UsrCtrl`, e.g. `ImageUrl`.

```

```
public string ImageUrl
{
    get
    {
        return this.ImageButton1.ImageUrl;
    }
    set
    {
        this.ImageButton1.ImageUrl = value;
    }
}
```

```

Then, within the `Button1_Click` method, use `this.UsrCtrl.ImageUrl = "~/Images/2.jpg";`.

I hope I understood your question correctly.

Comment: I have put the aforementioned code in the .ascx file. In the main page code I have written: ... if (c.GetType() == typeof(Lamp)) { ((Lamp)c).ImageUrl = "green_lamp.jpg"; } but it doesn't work. ("Lamp" is my custom control.) Why?